# Full Adder in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'll be teaching Computer Architecture at the undergraduate level this fall and want to make sure that my example Verilog code follows best practices. I welcome any suggestions, however minor, for improving this code, which [runs at EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3brY).

Our textbook is *Computer Organization and Design* by Hennessy and Patterson. It doesn't say much about Verilog, and I will only be taking a small piece of code from an appendix, so there is no style to be consistent with.

**Testbench**

```
module test;
  reg   a;
  reg   b;
  reg   c_in;
  wire  sum;
  wire  c_out;

  ADDER adder(a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
          
  initial begin
    // Dump waves
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) begin
      {a, b, c_in} = i;
      display;
    end
  end
  
  task display;
    #1;
    $display("%b + %b + %b = %b%b", a, b, c_in, c_out, sum);
  endtask
  
endmodule
```

**Design**

```
module ADDER (a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
  input     a;
  input     b;
  input     c_in;
  output    sum;
  output    c_out;

  assign c_out = (a & b) | (a & c_in) | (b & c_in);
  assign sum = a ^ b ^ c_in;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the design module, use ANSI-style port declarations to reduce redundant port lists (refer to IEEE-Std 1800-2017, section 23.2.1 *Module header definition*):

```
module ADDER (
  input     a,
  input     b,
  input     c_in,
  output    sum,
  output    c_out
);
```

In the testbench, use connections-by-name instead of connections-by-order:

```
ADDER adder (
    .a     (a),
    .b     (b),
    .c_in  (c_in),
    .sum   (sum),
    .c_out (c_out)
);
```

This involves more typing, but it avoids common connection errors, and it makes the code easier to understand (more self-documenting).  Refer to Std section
23.3.2.2 *Connecting module instance ports by name*.

I usually find it helpful for debugging to also display the time:

```
$display($time, " %b + %b + %b = %b%b", a, b, c_in, c_out, sum);
```

I also find it easier to debug if the signal values are displayed when they are stable (away from signal edges).  This can be accomplished by adding a small delay after the `$display` as well as before it:

```
  task display;
    #1;
    $display($time, " %b + %b + %b = %b%b", a, b, c_in, c_out, sum);
    #1;
  endtask
```